# Getting an object back when should be a string

Tags: meteor

I've got this client code that pushes some data into a collection called `Hours` and then displays it in a template called `hoursWorked`

```js
Template.loggedIn.events({
  "submit .inputHours": function (event) {
    var projectInput = event.target.projectInput.value;
    var hoursInput = event.target.hoursInput.value;

    Hours.insert({
      project: projectInput,
      hours: hoursInput,
      createdAt: new Date() // current time
    });

    event.target.hours.value = "";

    console.log(project + " - " + hours + " success");
    return false;
  }
});

Template.hoursWorked.helpers({
  hours: function () {
    return Hours.find();
  }
});
```

Then the html looks like this

```html
<template name="hoursWorked">
  {{#each hours}}
    <h1>{{project}}</h1>
    <p>{{hours}}</p>
    <p>{{createdAt}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

But I'm getting back something that looks like this:

```
Option1
[object Object]
Fri Feb 13 2015 00:14:32 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Why am I receiving an object when the rest of them are strings and how can I get it to just display the text value being inputed? Note: `projectInput` is a select form with multiple options and `hoursInput` is a text input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template helpers override fields on the data context with the same name.

```html
<template name="hoursWorked">
  {{#each hours}}
    <h1>{{project}}</h1>
    <p>{{hours}}</p> <!-- here -->
    <p>{{createdAt}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The `{{hours}}` marked with `<!-- here -->` will still refer to the helper, even if there is an `hours` field inside the data context.

The simplest fix is just to rename the helper:

```js
Template.hoursWorked.helpers({
    hoursDocuments: function () {
        return Hours.find();
    }
});
```

```html
<template name="hoursWorked">
  {{#each hoursDocuments}}
    <h1>{{project}}</h1>
    <p>{{hours}}</p>
    <p>{{createdAt}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are referencing the parent still, and you need to reference `hours.hours` instead

```
<template name="hoursWorked">
  {{#each hours}}
    <h1>{{project}}</h1>
    <p>{{hours.hours}}</p>
    <p>{{createdAt}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Or you could change the name of your return:

```
Template.hoursWorked.helpers({
    hoursWorked: function () {
      return Hours.find();
    }
});

<template name="hoursWorked">
  {{#each hoursWorked}}
    <h1>{{project}}</h1>
    <p>{{hours}}</p>
    <p>{{createdAt}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```